# current_user set to nil in rails / devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Experiencing a very strange bug with rails 4.1.3 and devise 3.0.4. Trying to handle anonymous logins. Either the user is logged in through devise or he has filled in name and email in a previous form.

Following code in the controller:

```
   logger.debug "current_user before:#{current_user.inspect}"
   if(current_user.nil?)
     current_user = User.create(:last_name => params[:guest_username], :email => params[:guest_email])
     logger.debug "Guest user created" 
   end
   logger.debug "current_user after:#{current_user.inspect}"
```

Following log output:

```
D, [2014-10-30T14:10:15.627130 #2148] DEBUG -- : current_user before:#<User _id: 52ffe1b35043001fa8000000, created_at: 2014-02-15 21:52:51 UTC, updated_at: 2014-10-30 13:00:47 UTC, email: "xxx@yyy.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$r5wXs97N.HIAp9bp5GZBaOUt8R5.S/Z/2PhcpF0xaIVuTD4BpZrmO", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 134, current_sign_in_at: 2014-10-30 13:00:47 UTC, last_sign_in_at: 2014-10-30 12:57:35 UTC, current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: 2014-02-15 21:53:04 UTC, confirmation_sent_at: 2014-02-15 21:52:51 UTC, unconfirmed_email: nil, image: "", first_name: "Dave", last_name: "Something", roles_mask: 7>
D, [2014-10-30T14:10:15.629130 #2148] DEBUG -- : current_user after:nil
```

So this is what I don't get, why is the current_user object being reset to nil even though the code in the if block is not being executed...

What's going on?

Thanks in advance - Mike

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
sign_in(current_user)
```

like this:

```
if(current_user.nil?)
  current_user = User.create(:last_name => params[:guest_username], :email => params[:guest_email])
  sign_in(current_user)
  logger.debug "Guest user created" 
end
logger.debug "current_user after:#{current_user.inspect}"
```

or set the instance variable:

```
if(current_user.nil?)
  @current_user = User.create(:last_name => params[:guest_username], :email => params[:guest_email])
  logger.debug "Guest user created" 
end
logger.debug "current_user after:#{current_user.inspect}"
```

Comment: Hi, my problem is when the user is logged in correctly through devise and thus current_user is defined. Somehow it is then destroyed, see the log output. I don't understand why...

Comment: It's because you're trying to create the user by yourself, let devise's session controller handle it for you, if you must change its code then be sure that you have the exact or almost same implementation of code.